# I have a DataGridView on my form that is not being displayed when I run my form. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView named statGrid on a panel named panel10. When I run the program, I use this code to populate and get to that DataGridView:

```
          PubVars.active = true;
      lblPanelTitle.Text = "Folder Status";
      using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(PubVars.connStr))
      {
        string query = "SELECT viewfldr, status FROM Folders WHERE username = '" + PubVars.usrName + "'";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connect))
        {
          connect.Open();
          da.Fill(dt);
          connect.Close();
        }

        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        style.Font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

        try
        {
          statGrid.DataSource = dt;

          statGrid.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Style = style;
          statGrid.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style = style;
          statGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
          statGrid.Columns[0].Width = 400;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
          return;
        }
      }

      panel1.Visible = false;
      panel2.Visible = false;
      panel3.Visible = false;
      panel4.Visible = false;
      panel5.Visible = false;
      panel6.Visible = false;
      panel7.Visible = false;
      panel8.Visible = false;
      panel9.Visible = false;
      panel10.Visible = true;

      statGrid.Focus();
```

When I run The form, and the code I get to the panel, but no DataGridView is shown. Could any one please tell me why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong here. You should check visibility of parent containers (if any) or datagridview. Might also be something related to dock or anchor properites

Answer (score 0):

I think You missed to call Bind() method try this `statGrid.Bind()`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. The parent to panel10 was not the form. it was panel9. When I moved panel10 directly under the form in the Document Outline tab, that fixed it. Thanks to you all who helped.